# Is there a more efficient way to create a large list of message consumers for JMS?

Tags: java, architecture, jms, messaging

I am looking at a design with circa 100 topics. Creating sessions, topics, message consumers and wiring the message listener to the consumer seems to use up a lot of resources. Is there a better way? For example could I reuse my session, or does it have to be created each time? Or should I use another paradigm?

Here is the logic which is being called at least a hundred times:

```
        session = conn.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        final Topic destination = session.createTopic(topicName);
        final MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination, selector);
        consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

JMS sessions are not thread safe so you must  create a new one for each subscription. Some  JMS implementations like ActiveMQ support virtual topics where a subscription can be initiated to multiple topics. This would probably solve your problem. See http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html.

Answer (score 0):

For the same queue and same consumer session can and should be reused. So you will have 100 sessions at maximum.

Another solution can involve some bridges with selectors on the JMS server. You can configure your jms to forward 100 topics to one or several queues and then consume from that queue. But it might be hard to implement if your message types are all different in those topics.

Hope that helps